# php xcopy giving 0 files copied

Tags: php

I am trying to do a xcopy in php, but I cant seem to get it to work, I did try going down the route of psexec but the copy command didn’t work either.

I have tried shell_exec,exec and passthru but all seem to be giving the same error 0 files copied, yet if I do the same command via command line the files copy perfectly, so it cant be a permissions issue, must be a issue with my code, if anyone can point out my problem I would be very grateful

when I execute this via command line it works:

```html
C:\Users\xante>xcopy c:\wamp\www\xcopy\copythis.bat  \\testmachine\c$\xcopied C:\wamp\www\xcopy\copythis.bat
1 File(s) copied
```

when i execute the same command via php i get this output:

```html
  Array ( [0] => 0 File(s) copied)  xcopy "c:\wamp\www\xcopy\copythis.bat" "\\testmachine\c$\xcopied\"
```

this is my php code:

```html
$host="testmachine";

$execute = ('xcopy "c:\\wamp\www\xcopy\copythis.bat"  "\\\"$host"\c$\xcopied\\"');
exec($execute,$output);
print_r ($output)."<br />";
echo $execute;
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out WAMP is a bit awkward and the issue wasn’t code related.

To fix the issue I have done the following:

- ran services.msc
- looked for wampapache,
- right clicked went to properties,
- clicked on logon and ticked the allow service to interact with desktop
- restarted wampapache and issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

try with this `$execute` variable

```
$execute = ('xcopy "c:\\wamp\\www\\xcopy\\copythis.bat"' .   '"\\\\' . $host . '\\c$\\xcopied\\"');
```

Comment: Please explain what your answer does.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk : correctifs : (1) UNC path need 4 backslash (2) variable $host to be interpreted must be inside a double quotes or without nothing (3) to avoid problems each backslash must be escaped

Comment: unfortunatly this is still not working with the code above it gives the same error 0 files copied.

Comment: i have noticed since doing abit more testing that the following gets outputted Array ( [0] => 0 File(s) copied)  xcopy "c:\wamp\www\xcopy\copythis.bat" "\\testmachine\c$\xcopied\"

Comment: it wont let me edit the above so, i have noticed since doing abit more testing that the following gets outputted Array ( [0] => 0 File(s) copied) xcopy "c:\wamp\www\xcopy\copythis.bat" "\\testmachine\c$\xcopied\" when running this comand line it doesnt work but if i remove the quotes it works command line any ideas on a work around?